# Solving a simple matrix in row-reduced form in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

Okay, I am pulling out all my hair on this one, though, as a noob, I am sure there are several problems. I want to take a matrix and, by sing elementary row operations, reduced it to row-reduced echelon form. We assume (1) it is solvable and (2) a unique solution. There is no checking for zeros or anything; it just does row operations. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void printmatrix(float A[][4]);
void RowReduce (float A[][4]);

int main() {

    // answer should be { 2, 4, -3 }
    float A[3][4] = {
        { 5, -6, -7,   7 },
        { 3, -2,  5, -17 },
        { 2,  4, -3,  29 }
    };

    printmatrix(A);
    RowReduce(A);

}

// Outputs the matrix
void printmatrix(float A[][4]) { 

    int p = 3;
    int q = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 

}

void RowReduce (float A[][4]){

    //rows
    int p = 3;  
    //columns
    int q = 4;  

    // the determines the column we are at which holds the diagonal,
    // the basis for all elimination above and below
    int lead = 0; 

    cout << endl;
    while ( lead < q - 1 ) {

        // for each row . . .
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)  {

            // ignore the diagonal, and we will not have a tree rref
            // as the diagonal will not be divided by itself. I can fix that.
            if ( i != lead )  {

                cout << A[lead][lead] << "  " << A[i][lead];

                for (int j = 0; j < q; j++) {

                    //here is the math . . . . probably where the problem is?
                    A[i][j]    = A[lead][lead] * A[i][j]; 
                    A[i][lead] = A[i][lead]    * A[lead][j];
                    A[i][j]    = A[i][j]       - A[i][lead];

                }

                cout << endl;

            }
        }

        // now go to the next pivot
        lead++;  
        cout << endl;

    }

}
```

I tried doing it by hand, but what I get is, of course, the right answer, but this gets a diagonal matrix--which is great--but the wrong answer!

Comment: Try to figure out how you're doing it by hand, and then replicate that behavior in code. (Of course, if I remember linear algebra correctly, how I did it by hand was mostly intuitive, and will therefore be extremely hard to replicate exactly in code... however, there are easy ways to do this that you can google.)

Comment: If it's supposed to do what you do by hand, then I'd insert a `printmatrix` call at the end of each pivot cycle. You'll (hopefully quickly) see how/where it goes wrong.

Comment: If this isn't for a school assignment, Eigen is a great linear algebra library for C++.

Comment: "probably where the problem is?" Are you using a debugger? Stepping through the code? Seeing the values of the variables?

Comment: Yes I did some of the intermediate printing and just can't narrow it down. I guess I was being hopeful that someone would go through the math for me and see where I went wrong, he he. :-)

Comment: If you'd do some debugging you'd see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 10):

The main error in you code is that you are calculating the divisor or multiplier within the for loop. You should calculate them before iterating over the cells.

Hint: debugging is easier if the code is well formated and the variables have meaningful names.

See the implementation of `RowReduce()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void printmatrix(float A[][4]);
void RowReduce(float A[][4]);

int main()
{
    float A[3][4] = {{5, -6, -7,   7},
                     {3, -2,  5, -17},
                     {2,  4, -3,  29}}; //answer should be {2, 4, -3}

    printmatrix(A);
    RowReduce(A);
}

void printmatrix(float A[][4]) // Outputs the matrix
{
    int p=3;
    int q=4;

    for (int i=0; i<p; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<q; j++) {
                    cout << setw(7) << setprecision(4) << A[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void RowReduce(float A[][4])
{
    const int nrows = 3; // number of rows
    const int ncols = 4; // number of columns

    int lead = 0; 

    while (lead < nrows) {
        float d, m;

        for (int r = 0; r < nrows; r++) { // for each row ...
            /* calculate divisor and multiplier */
            d = A[lead][lead];
            m = A[r][lead] / A[lead][lead];

            for (int c = 0; c < ncols; c++) { // for each column ...
                if (r == lead)
                    A[r][c] /= d;               // make pivot = 1
                else
                    A[r][c] -= A[lead][c] * m;  // make other = 0
            }
        }

        lead++;
        printmatrix(A);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
  5      -6      -7       7 
  3      -2       5     -17 
  2       4      -3      29 


  1    -1.2    -1.4     1.4 
  0     1.6     9.2   -21.2 
  0     6.4    -0.2    26.2 

  1       0     5.5   -14.5 
  0       1    5.75  -13.25 
  0       0     -37     111 

  1       0       0       2 
  0       1       0       4 
  0       0       1      -3
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Not sure, however, what is wrong with mine. I also tried to do mine as I would have done by hand. Yours is a different means to get the same ends, but I am not sure still where I went wrong. Thanks for your effort though!

Comment: Is there a way to make it work for : 
1 2 3 4 /
0 0 1 1 /
0 0 1 1 /